# One to one EF relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a database that looks like this:

[image]

Where TableA is the principal and TableB is the dependent.

I'm trying to create this relationship in the DB using Entity Framework. The connection from TableB to TableA works, but the opposite does not (TableA to TableB).

```
public partial class TableA
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public virtual TableB tableB { get; set; }
}

public partial class TableB
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long TableA_ID { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }   
    [ForeignKey("TableA_ID")]   
    public virtual TableA tableA { get; set; }
}
```

Each time I get the error:

> Because the dependent role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the dependent role must be '*'

or the error:

> The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

I tried adding `[Required]` in TableB above `public virtual TableA tableA` and in other places but nothing seems to work.

Can you please help me create such relationship (using data annotations only, if possible)?

Comment: Did you define this relationship in the `OnModelCreating()` override of `DbContext`?

Comment: I didnt define it in OnModelCreating. but I understand I can do this using data annotations?

Comment: What version of EF?  In EF6 you can only have 1-1 relationships if the foreign key is the entity key.

Comment: Yep, 6. So I cant do this with the current DB setup? How can I change it to work?

Comment: Make the FK from Table_B to Table_A the PK, or simply let it be a 1-many relationship in EF.

Answer (score -2):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.Tables.Add(TableA);
ds.Relations.Add("TableB", TableA.Columns["id"], TableB.Columns["TableA_ID"]);
ds.Relations["TableB"].Nested = true;
```

If I understand correctly. You can try this.

Comment: I would like to use data annotations only, if possible